# Configure ISAPI redirector: worker propreties for IIS and Liferay

Tags: iis, liferay, tomcat7, isapi, isapi-redirect

we have fronted Liferay tomcat server with IIS , and we used ISAPI tomcat redirector for that ,everything works just fine.
the problem is that We need to map a specific Domain name to a specific URL on Liferay:

1. workers.properties :

   > ```
   > worker.mydomain_com.port=8014
   > worker.mydomain_com.host=127.0.0.1
   > worker.mydomain_com=ajp13
   > ```
2. uriworkermap.properties

   > ```
   > /mydomain.com/=mydomain_com
   > /www.mydomain.com=mydomain_com
   > /www.mydomain.com/*=mydomain_com
   > ```

This configuration will map  `www.mydomain.com` to `localhost:xxxx` .
what i want is how to configure the worker `mydomain_com` so it can be mapped to `localhost:xxxx/web/organiation`. I searched for `worker.mydomain.`options but there is no configuration for the uri, is there any way to do ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your configuration in IIS for mapping to www.mydomain.com is working fine. Its better to keep it like that and enable friendly URL for site in liferay so that you don't really need /web/organiation

Here are the steps to do in liferay 6.1

- Login to Liferay as administration.

  - Go to Control Panel
  - Select your site and then click on "Site Settings".
  - Click on "Site URL" in right side.
  - Under "Virtual Hosts", you should see a text box named "Public Pages"
  - Enter www.mydomain.com and save.

Then liferay automatically redirect requests coming to it from www.mydomain.com to public pages of this site.

If you are using different liferay version, steps may be little different. But it still provides an option to set domain name for site.

Comment: is this working for many domains ? such as a domain for every organization

Comment: Yes, you can have different domain for every site. Do you want for organization or site ? as of liferay 6, you can have pages only for Site and a site can be associated to an organization.

Comment: I'm using liferay 6.1, for every organization and both private and public sites,  ill try this later thanks  since the server is on production now, I tell you if it is working . thank you